# Attribute table values randomly disappear or are changed

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, spatial-analysis

I'm using 3.10.14 version of QGIS and something very strange started happening. I performed several attraction distance and attraction reach analyses (using the [Place Syntax Too](https://www.smog.chalmers.se/pst)l) that I saved in the same layer. Then I would usually duplicate that layer (right click -> duplicate layer) to change the visualization settings to create different maps. I have been doing this over the course of 2 months. When I opened the project recently I saw that the values for some of the analyses in the attribute table had changed either to NULL or to a mix of 1, 0 and NULL. After I redo the analysis it looks fine again, but when opening it after a couple of hours it has changed again.

Do you have any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Update: The file was saved as geopackage. I'm attaching screenshots of most part of the attribute table and the field types.
[image: Attribute table-part 1]

[image: Attribute table-part 2]

[image: Fields table]

Comment: Please name tools or plugins correctly.

Comment: Just edited in the post.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "place syntax tool" in QGIS?

Comment: https://www.smog.chalmers.se/pst
You can download it here.

But there's nothing wrong with the analyses themselves. What im wondering about is whether this qgis behavior of values disappearing from the attribute table has happened to someone else before or am i doing something wrong when saving files or smth similar?

Comment: Then it's not a tool, but a plugin. Can you provide a screenshot of how your attribute table looks like after several rounds of analysis and duplicating?

Comment: It might be that you set the wrong data type. Besides what @Erik asked, please provide the data format you are using (i.e. SHP file or other) and the data types for the relevant fields.

Comment: Yes, its a plugin called Place Syntax Tool. Ive now updated the post with the attribute table and field types.

Comment: Do you have the same behavior if you save it to a shapefile?  If not do you get different field types when you look at the shapefile?  When your layer looks correct, if you use the Refactor Fields tool on it, and set proper field lengths and precisions for the real numbers,  and save that, does that stick?

Comment: It might be caused by the plugin itself. In its source code(in [`pst/model/model.py, line 295`](https://github.com/SMoG-Chalmers/PST/blob/master/pstqgis/src/pst/model/model.py#L295)), when defining a field, the length (`len`) and precision (`prec`) of the field are not specified. And they are `0` as default ([reference](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsField.html#ac179c02e76b6e14e380d0ddb1618e9a3)). I'm not sure, tough.

Comment: Hard to know if this comes from the tool or QGIS, I would still suggest to update to a recent version of QGIS in the event where this issue is fixed.

Comment: 1.  Is the data store (geopackage) on a local disk, or a network file share?  2.  Is it stored in a folder that is synchronised with a shared file service (such as Drop Box, One Drive, iCloud, etc)?  3.  When the values change, do they always revert to the same values, or are they different each time?